# Get result outside Vue istance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm using VUE and Axio to Get a Json from an API. But when I'm trying to put the results that i received from API in a var outside the Vue Instance, it's saying that the item is null. (If I go to console and call vueinstance.results, i got the results).

```
var vueinstance = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data(){
        return {results: null }
         } ,
    methods: {
        callApiSearch: function (searchQuery) {
            axios
                .post('api/search', searchQuery)
                .then(response => (this.results = response.data))
        }
    }
});

var ajaxSearch = function callApi(searchQuery) {
    //Build Search Query
    if (typeof searchQuery === "string" || searchQuery instanceof String) {
        searchQuery = { Query: searchQuery };
    }
    vueinstance.callApiSearch(searchQuery);

    var test = vueinstance.results; <====== **HERE THE VALUE IS COMING NULL**

}
```

Anyone can help me with that? Thanks.

Comment: your `callApiSearch` is making a server request, which is an async operation. In your code above, `test` is getting set to the inital value of `results` before the server request has finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `callApiSearch` method is performing an async operation; the `then` callback will be executed once the HTTP response is received which will occur *after* you accessed `vueinstance.results`.

I suggest you read up on JavaScript async concepts, promises, concurrency, etc so that you can understand this better. There's plenty of resources online about this.

To fix it, make sure your `callApiSearch` function returns the promise:

```js
callApiSearch: function (searchQuery) {
  return axios
    .post('api/search', searchQuery)
    .then(response => (this.results = response.data))
}
```

Then when you call the method, you can use `then` on the returned promise to execute code once the request has completed:

```js
vueinstance
  .callApiSearch(searchQuery)
  .then(() => {
    console.log(vueinstance.results)
  })
```

Comment: Decade, thank you very much for your help, however this solution did not work for me.

i need to put the results in an global variable that i can access outside the .then() 

`var ajaxSearch = function callApi(searchQuery) {
 var test1 = "";
 //Build Search Query
 if (typeof searchQuery === "string" || searchQuery instanceof String) {
        searchQuery = { Query: searchQuery };
    }
    // vueinstance.callApiSearch(searchQuery);
 
 vueinstance.callApiSearch(searchQuery).then(() => {
  test1 =  vueinstance.results;
   })
   
   console.log(test1); <=== Does not work
}`

Comment: Yes, that won't for the same reason in your original code. Your `console.log(test1)` statement should be inside the `then` callback function. I won't go into detail here because there is already plenty of learning material online for how to write async code.